# How break symlinks but preserve directory contents on Linux

Tags: linux, symlink

I have a directory structure like what is shown below

```
foo/
   bar/
     a.txt
     b.py
     c.py
```

and if you do ls -l you would see something like

```
test@test:/home/foo$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1        48 Oct 21 12:14 bar -> /lib/python2.7/site-packages/linked_dir/
```

so the contents of bar/ and linked_dir/ are the same because of the link.

I want to break the link but retain the bar/ directory and its contents. What I have seen online to break a link is `rm <link>` but that entirely removes the bar/ directory. Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Copy everything in `linked_dir` to `bar.new` subdirectory. Remove the `bar` symlink and rename `bar.new` to `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy whatever the symlink points to. By using `-L`, cp will dereference the symlink:

`cp -rL bar new-bar`

Delete the symlink:

`rm bar`

Rename your new copy to the original name:

`mv new-bar bar`